# date('d.m.Y H:i:s', (int)$record['crdate']) produces sometimes a wrong output

Tags: php, date

`date('d.m.Y H:i:s', (int)$aRecord['crdate'])` produces sometimes a wrong output e.g. "24.02..2022 18:36:32"

How could this happen?

Comment: The wrong part being the double dot after the month? I don't see how it would be possible, that this comes from `date` itself. Can you show a _reproducible_ example  of the problem?